# Conocer tracking de peticiones

Tags: php, javascript, html, nodejs

queria saber si existe alguna manera de saber de donde proviene una peticion a mi web site?

Me explico:

Si estoy en un proceso de marketing, sin utilizar Google Analytics, y coloco un link de mi sitio en alguna otra web y una persona le da click y quiero saber de que URL proviene. Se puede?

De antemano gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Se me ocurre que dentro de la liga lo tagges tipo `utm` como lo hacen esas herramientas de analisis. Después capturas esos valores de tu liga que dices que colocas en otra web con javascript y la almacenas en alguna BD.